# Java jdbc Resultset data not updated if any change in database

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, resultset

I'm using TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE so that my resultset is sensitive to any changes,
Now what i have understood, while reading from database resultset maintained cursor in the database
.Any (commit)changes to tuples in the database  while reading must be reflected in result.
But this not happening in my scenario.
i m using mysql. 
Is resultset caching in memory ????

```
 PreparedStatement  st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM user",ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    ResultSet res = st.executeQuery();
    res.setFetchSize(1);

    while (res.next()) {
         System.out.println(res.getString("name"));
      bufferRead.readLine();   //hold
    }
```

Comment: when you make change in database have you make commit for that change..?

Comment: you should try `st.executeUpdate();`

Comment: Yes i Commit the changes.

Comment: Not all database support scroll sensitive, or only support scroll sensitive for changes in the own transaction. You might want to check 1) if the result set is actually scroll sensitive (downgrading is allowed) and 2) what behavior is supported by MySQL.

Comment: So ur saying Mysql might not support scroll sensitive.

Comment: You have to check the notes for the jdbc driver to see if the driver you are using supports this.